# Is it possible to use apiblueprint for defining soap API documentation?

Tags: apiblueprint

I tried and I have problems with resource groups. I tried to create a custom group "Events" and list all function names related to events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid the frank answer is no.

The number of actions an API Blueprint Resource can have is currently limited by the number of HTTP Request Methods. At the moment the API Blueprint is made for APIs that are leveraging the HTTP – and as such it is leaning towards the resource-oriented architecture.

With that being said we are constantly evaluating the possible use other protocol layers and (better) support for various API architecture styles.

Comment: I ended up using middleman ruby gem with all the data kept in the yaml files.